# php sdk retrieve and store video_id after upload

Tags: video, facebook-php-sdk

I'm currently working on an application for users to upload videos which I then would like to display in my application.

I've been looking at this How-to : http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/515/#video_upload

I might be wrong but from what I understand (and have tried) users can only upload a video to a page for which they have admin rights. So I don't understand the purpose of the how-to unless such application is aimed to page admins only ?

But this is not my main problem since I'm OK with uploading the user's video to his own page.

My main problem resides in retrieving the video ID which is returned once the user uploaded his video.

When I test the application based on the How-to script I mentioned above, once the file is chosen and sent through the form, the page shows the `video_id` this way :

```
{
id:xxxxxxxx
}
```

And I don't get how I'm supposed to retrieve it in my php script ? Furthermore how can I redirect the user back to my appplication ?

For example Youtube's API has a `'nexturl'` variable added to the `$posturl` to redirect to a URL which will also include a `video_id` variable accessible through the `GET` method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to create your own PHP script to process the form and in that script use something like curl to make the POST to facebook so you can capture the response.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've looked up curl and from what I've seen it seems you need to have the file on your server which is out of the question in my case.
I'm trying to have the file uploaded directly from the user's drive to facebook.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the file will be stored on your server in a temp directory by PHP anyway...  Take a look at this example https://github.com/webdevhub/Picture-upload-Facebook-Server which shows how to do what I was suggesting but for a photo.  Should be similar for video.

Answer (score 0):

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I understand your idea however I don't understand how to control the data facebook returns once the file has been  uploaded through the form.
It looks as facebook "takes control" of the canva page and I don't know how to avoid that and have the data returned to my .php page instead.
Have you any clue on how to achieve this ?